# Chrome Hardware acceleration not working after upgrading ubuntu from 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, google-chrome, 14.10

> **Graphics Feature Status**

- **Canvas**: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- **Flash**: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- **Flash Stage3D**: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- **Flash Stage3D Baseline profile**: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- **Compositing**: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- **Multiple Raster Threads**: Disabled
- **Rasterization**: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- **Threaded Rasterization**: Unavailable
- **Video Decode**: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- **Video Encode**: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- **WebGL**: Unavailable

> **Driver Bug Workarounds**

- clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
- count_all_in_varyings_packing
- disable_ext_occlusion_query
- disable_post_sub_buffers_for_onscreen_surfaces
- scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args

> **Problems Detected**

- GPU process was unable to boot: GPU access is disabled in chrome://settings.
- Disabled Features: all
- EXT_occlusion_query appears to be buggy with Intel GPUs on Linux
- Applied Workarounds: disable_ext_occlusion_query
- Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764,
  349137
- Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
- Mesa drivers in Linux handle varyings without static use incorrectly:
  333885
- Applied Workarounds: count_all_in_varyings_packing
- Disable partial swaps on linux drivers: 339493
- Applied Workarounds: disable_post_sub_buffers_for_onscreen_surfaces
- Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent: 398694
- Applied Workarounds: scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
- Raster is using a single thread.
- Disabled Features: multiple_raster_threads

> **Version Information**

- Data exported    12/16/2014, 11:54:57 AM
- Chrome version   Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Operating system    Linux
  3.16.3-031603-generic
- Software rendering list version  0
- Driver bug list version  7.10
- ANGLE commit id  04ab0eb41f1b
- 2D graphics backend  Skia
- Command Line Args    --flag-switches-begin --ignore-gpu-blacklist
  --flag-switches-end

> **Driver Information**

- Initialization time  21
- Sandboxed    true
- GPU0 VENDOR = 0x8086, DEVICE= 0x0046
- Optimus  false
- AMD switchable   false
- Driver vendor    Mesa
- Driver version   10.3.0
- Driver date
- Pixel shader version 1.20
- Vertex shader version    1.20
- Machine model name
- Machine model version
- GL_VENDOR    Intel Open Source Technology Center
- GL_RENDERER  Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile
- GL_VERSION   2.1 Mesa 10.3.0
- GL_EXTENSIONS    GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra
  GL_EXT_blend_color
- GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_copy_texture
- GL_EXT_polygon_offset GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture_object
- GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_texture
- GL_EXT_texture3D GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_ARB_point_parameters
- GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_packed_pixels
  GL_EXT_point_parameters
- GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_separate_specular_color
- GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap
- GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp
  GL_SGIS_texture_lod
- GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
- GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat
- GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map
- GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_transpose_matrix
  GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
- GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_secondary_color
- GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
- GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_INGR_blend_func_separate
  GL_NV_blend_square
- GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection
  GL_NV_texture_env_combine4
- GL_S3_s3tc GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp
- GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_EXT_framebuffer_object
- GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_combine
- GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil
- GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_occlusion_query
- GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar
- GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
  GL_ARB_window_pos
- GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_NV_depth_clamp
- GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object
  GL_ARB_draw_buffers
- GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects
- GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ATI_draw_buffers
- GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_shadow_funcs
- GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_NV_primitive_restart
- GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow
  GL_ARB_half_float_pixel
- GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_point_sprite
  GL_ARB_shading_language_100
- GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two
  GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
- GL_OES_read_format GL_ARB_color_buffer_float
  GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
- GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_float
  GL_ARB_texture_rectangle
- GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object
- GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc
- GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB
  GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent
- GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit
  GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil
- GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_ARB_vertex_array_object
  GL_ATI_separate_stencil
- GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced
  GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters
- GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_integer
  GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode
- GL_EXT_timer_query GL_OES_EGL_image GL_AMD_performance_monitor
- GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_draw_instanced
- GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays
  GL_ARB_map_buffer_range
- GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra
- GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra
  GL_NV_conditional_render
- GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility
- GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex
- GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions
- GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sampler_objects
  GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map
- GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_texture_query_lod
  GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui
- GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_EXT_provoking_vertex
- GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba
  GL_ARB_get_program_binary
- GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects
  GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding
- GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5
- GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_internalformat_query
- GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_texture_storage
- GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object
  GL_ARB_copy_image
- GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata
- GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_KHR_debug GL_ARB_buffer_storage
- GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_multi_bind
- GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture
- GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge
- GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev
- GL_INTEL_performance_query
- Window system binding vendor SGI
- Window system binding version    1.4
- Window system binding extensions GLX_ARB_create_context
- GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
- GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_ARB_multisample
- GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
- GLX_EXT_import_context GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
  GLX_EXT_visual_info
- GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer GLX_OML_swap_method
- GLX_SGI_swap_control GLX_SGIS_multisample GLX_SGIX_fbconfig
  GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
- GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group GLX_INTEL_swap_event
- Window manager   Compiz
- XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP  Unity
- GDMSESSION   ubuntu
- Compositing manager  Yes
- Direct rendering Yes
- Reset notification strategy  0x8261
- GPU process crash count  3

> **Log Messages**

- GpuProcessHostUIShim: The GPU process crashed!
- GpuProcessHostUIShim: The GPU process crashed!
- GpuProcessHostUIShim: The GPU process crashed!

Comment: You can delete the preference file using the below command %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ . This will remove all the settings about Chrome.

Comment: I have deleted the /home/user/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preference file and restarted chrome but still same issue.